# Going to another commit in GitHub Desktop (GUI VERSION)

Tags: github, github-for-windows

How do I go to a previous commit from GitHub Desktop? I did some work in my class yesterday and today when I pulled it said I needed to resolve merges, so I clicked continue from Main. Now I do not have the version in my unity, but I do have it in History. I would like to go back to that version.

[image: The selected version is the one I would like to go back to.]

[image: The one on the top has a unique option to Ammend the commit.]

I do not have the command line, please only options on GUI version.

I do not want to try anything without asking because last time it caused a lot of errors and corruption in my previous project.

Answer (score 0):

`Create branch from commit` is probably your best bet. It will ask you to enter a name for the new branch. Once your done you can use the branch tab to switch back to your development branch.